# Understanding part of log4j2 configuration file

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am able to understand log4j2 configuration via XML, however I have some confusion when we configure it via properties file.

```
1. appender.console.type = Console
2. appender.console.name = STDOUT
3. appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
```

In line 1, we use `console` at two places, so which one really tells that I want to use `ConsoleAppender`, and what does `appender.console` represent? I understand that in XML we specify `Console` as the appender type and we give it a name using `name` attribute, so that we can refer to it later in the `Logger` element.

Comment: Parameters in properties files serves the same purpose as that of xml files.

Answer (score 0):

In `appender.console` console is the identifier for this component. It's the same as the `name` attribute in the XML configuration.

In your case you could also achieve the same configuration with:

```
appender.foo.type = Console
appender.foo.name = STDOUT
appender.foo.layout.type = PatternLayout
```

See [the docs](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#Properties) for more information.

**What is the appender.foo.name property used for?**
The [docs for appenders](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html) state that "*Appenders always have a name so that they can be referenced from Loggers.*" For each logger you have to reference at least one appender so that the logmessages are written out somewhere. Use the name you defined earlier for that.

In your example you would add the appender to a logger like this:

```
rootLogger.level = info
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

Comment: Thanks. But then what is `appender.console.name` for?

Comment: I updated the answer. Hope that makes it more clear. Maybe you should have a look at the XML configuration. It's much clearer in my opinion.